# C fscanf discarding extra characters if there is any

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I'm working on this project for one of my classes and it states, "Discard everything after the three digit characters up to and including the next newline or EOF".

For example, the following would be a example test configuration file:

```
119
3561234
263abc
```

I need to save the first three digit characters to individual variables defined as row, column, value (respectively).

The code I have so far is the following:

```
/*
 * Read in the initial puzzle configuration.
 * Each line is 4 characters long:
 *   Row    as a character '0' .. '9'
 *   Column as character '0' .. '9'
 *   Digit  as character '0' .. '9'
 *   Terminating newline.
 * Exits with an error message if there are syntactic
 * or semantic errors with any configuration line.
 */

void configure(FILE *puzzle_file) {

    int row, column, value; // Variables
    int count = 1; //the counter for what line we are on 

    /*
     * Loops through every line transforming the chars to character int values
     * for each int needed and addes it to puzzle and changes fixed values
     * at same location.
     */
    while((fscanf(puzzle_file, "%1i%1i%1i%*[^\n]", &row, &column, &value)) != EOF){
            if(!in_range(row) || !in_range(column) || !in_range(value)){
                    printf("Illegal format in configuration file at line %i\n", count);
                    exit(1);
            }
            if(puzzle[row][column] != 0){
                    printf("Illegal placement in configuration file at line %i\n",count);
                    exit(1);
            }

            puzzle[row][column] = value;
            fixed[row][column] = 1;

            count++;
    }

}
```

I would expect that 9 would go in row 1 and column 1, 6 go in row 3 and column 5, and 3 would go in row 2 and column 6.

With a proper formated config file it will go into the first if statement and end there.

Proper config file example:

```
123
356
235
etc..
```

I'm assuming its my fscanf thats making it not work correctly. How would you change that so it would do that?

EDIT 1:

in_range function:

```
/*
 * Return TRUE iff the value is in the Sudoku range (1 .. 9)
 */
static bool in_range(int value) {

    if(isdigit(value) && value != 0){
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Will add additional code if needed.

Comment: Is that a regular expression at the end of your format string?  C doesn't have regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>It would appear you think `fscanf()` uses regular expressions.</strike>

It doesn't. C doesn't have regular expressions.

I *think* you're looking for:

```
fscanf(puzzle_file, "%1i%1i%1i%*s", &row, &column, &value)
```

This will grab the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd characters as integers, then the remaining data on the line will not be stored in a variable.

I'd never seen `[^/n]` in scanf, and apparently that's not the problem.

I suspect the problem is in your `in_range()` function. What is that?

**Edit since additional code was posted:**

Your `fscanf` was fine. Your `in_range()` is not. `isdigit()` tells you whether or not a *character* is a digit.

Re-reading your requirements, I suggest this for your line reading logic:

```
char buffer[5];
int row, column, value;
int count = 1;
while(fgets(buffer, 5, puzzleFile) != NULL)
{
    if ( (buffer[3] == '\n') 
          && (sscanf(buffer, "%1i%1i%1i%*[^\n]", &row, &column, &value) == 3))
    {
         puzzle[row][column] = value;
    }
    else
    {
          printf("Illegal format in configuration file at line %i\n", count);
          exit(1);
    }
    count++;

}
```

This guarantees that each line is 3 characters with a newline. `%1i` in sscanf guarantees that each character is a digit in the range of 0-9 if all three matched and were assigned to your variables (it returns the number of assignments).

Comment: False, C has regular expressions; not built into the language itself but POSIX regex does exist see regex.h.

Comment: ::sigh:: Yes, you can write a regular expression engine in C. Considering that's what the interpreters and compilers for most languages that include regular expressions are written in, it kinda makes sense. It is **not part of the language itself**.

Comment: And POSIX regex wouldn't be my first choice. I'd personally recommend the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org).

Comment: Ive tried fscanf(puzzle_file, "%1i%1i%1i%*s", &row, &column, &value) and it's still giving me a "Illegal format in configuration file at line 1" error.

Comment: POSIX is the one that is built into GLib C which is why I had indicated it.  libpcre works as well.

Comment: My scanf foo might be weak, I haven't used it in years to try and do what you're doing. If you have to deal with formatting errors in the file, I think a better approach would be to simply read the lines into a buffer and parse them.

Comment: So like use getline() to pass it into a string array then parse that string?

Comment: Would probably be the best to use a regex with capture groups; it would be more robust.

Comment: Because the only problem with that fscanf is that if the line is proper formatted (digit, digit, digit, \n) It will cause the error to ensue

Comment: His `%*[^\n]` is perfectly fine. It's called a `scanset`, and every (conforming) implementation of `fscanf` (and scanf, sscanf, etc.) supports it. `"*s"` is not a real replacement -- it will skip whitespace, then read and ignore consecutive non-whitespace, and stop, so file contained something like "123 junk more junk", it would leave " more junk" in the input.

Comment: @Destroyer - I just tested the fscanf pattern, it works fine. What does `in_range()` do?

Comment: @Brian Roach: It checks if row, column, and value if it is a digit and between 1-9, I can like code for that if you need. (Its short)

Comment: Yes, Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: Sorry for delay, its added now.

Comment: I think my last edit should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Brian Roach: Ok so after some investigation I found out that It wasn't my line input that was giving me errors, it was my is_range function and add_digit and erase_digit function that was throwing me off on my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading a line at a time from the file into a buffer using something like `getline()`.  Then use

`sscanf(buffer, "%1d%1d%1d", &row, &column, &value);`

to scan the values into your variables.

Comment: So it would be like while(getline(puzzle_file, tempstr) != EOF){ sscanf(tempstr, %1i%1i%1i, &row, &column, &value) //do work } ?

Comment: @DestroyerDust: yes - the `getline()` deals with getting a complete line, and the `sscanf()` interprets just the first three characters; I'm assuming that the missing quotes etc will be fixed.  This also deals with embedded spaces etc in the debris.

Comment: Yup, something like that should do the job.  I think getline requires a malloc-allocated buffer or it can allocate one for you.  You might want to read the documentation for it. If getline() isn't available to you, you can use fgets() instead.  In that case, it would be something like while (fgets(tempstr, sizeof(tempstr), puzzle_file) != EOF){ sscanf(tempstr, %1i%1i%1i, &row, &column, &value) //do work }

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Ok, I will try that in a second.

Comment: Were "technically not" as-pose to be dealing with memory allocation and pointers for this project. So bringing up that point I think getline may be out of the question.